# No custom themes appearing in either Unity Tweaker, or Tweaker tool

Tags: unity, gnome, icons, themes

Okay so I am trying to install both of these here:

[Obsidian 2](https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1173113/)

[Obsidian Icon theme](https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1169579/)

The website uses a handy auto installer that automatically downloads the files and moves them into the **.themes** folder inside the home directory, I've made sure that the file is there, I have both **Tweak Tool** and **Unity Tweak tool** installed.

I restart the computer (even though you dont need to, I just do it to be sure) make sure the files are still there, and then open unity tweak tool and tweak tool, and try to change the theme. Though nothing new shows, it still has the stock themes inside of the list.

I've done this with another theme before and it worked on the first try but it seems that any other themes that I try to install never work unless they are installed via PPA, which is the only way I see works 100% of the time.

is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It should be in `.themes` folder. Not `.Themes`.

Comment: I checked and I have the folder set as ".themes" I just typed it wrong in the question, thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: what's the output of `find  ~/.themes -type d` in terminal

Comment: I get the directories of other themes along with obsidian. I won't paste it all since it won't fit but here:

/home/scott/.themes/theme-obsidian-2-master
**/home/scott/.themes/theme-obsidian-2-master/Obsidian-2**

everything here is under the bolded directory (without quotes)

"/openbox-3"
"/gtk-3.0"
"/gtk-3.0/apps"
"/gtk-3.0/assets"
"/gnome-shell"
"/gnome-shell/assets"
"/gnome-shell/assets/dot"
"/gtk-2.0"
"/gtk-2.0/pixmap"
"/metacity-1"

Comment: You should put `Obsidian-2` folder directly inside `.themes` folder. Then you will see it in tweak tool.

Comment: That's because a theme is recognized only if a `index.theme`  is present inside the folder present inside `.themes`. It doesn't search for `index.theme` recursively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a theme to be visible inside gnome/unity tweak tool, the `index.theme` file should be present inside the folder, which is present inside `.themes`.

In this way a theme is recognized. The `index.theme` file is not searched recursively in the directories inside `.themes`.

Therefore in your case, you should put `Obsidian-2` folder directly inside `.themes` folder. Then you will see it in tweak tool.

You can do so either in file manager or by running command `mv  ~/.themes/theme-obsidian-2-master/Obsidian-2/ ~/.themes/ && rm -R ~/.themes/theme-obsidian-2-master/` in terminal.

Comment: okay, this just makes me feel all dumb now since it's been the main reason none of the themes have been working.  :') but thank you! I was confused because, in the readme file inside of the master folder, it says just to keep the master folder inside of .themes. But this clears it up completely

I've found installing themes and icons via PPA or through Synaptics is much easier at least in my opinion.